# Continuous integration with Yii

Tags: testing, yii, continuous-integration

I have implemented the unit testing with Yii and phpUnit. I want to do more, please help me with this.I am developing ma software in multiple local machines. I wanna keep a repository and want to automate the merging of local developments and test it..kind of continuous integration.

Any one have such suggestion?

Comment: With distributed version control systems like git or mercurial you can do ít and many more things. Tris kind of tools are for any programming language , not only for yii or php

Comment: yea, But if there is an opensource version ?

Comment: Git or mercurial are open source :)

Comment: but is it suitable for private projects ?

Comment: I use git. You are free to use the software on any scope or kind of project. License Is GPL v2 (license for git ; your project can use any existing license). Is an external tool, not part of your software. See oficial page for more details http://git-scm.com/about/free-and-open-source

Comment: In this article is full explained licensing when use git for your project  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99168/do-i-have-to-release-my-code-as-open-source-if-i-use-git

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have much experiece working with [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) applications, I'm offering you to use SVN as your revision control software.
For Continues integration, there are [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), and [phpci](https://www.phptesting.org/) on top. for example you can configure your ci server to build & run all the test unit after each commit (via jenkins hook system) and in case of any failed test, send an email to commiter and so on.